# In OCaml, what type definition is this: 'a. unit -> 'a

Tags: ocaml

### Questions

It was my first time I saw a type definition like `'a. unit -> 'a` in [Explicit polymorphic type in record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320990/explicit-polymorphic-type-in-record)

**Q1**: What is this `'a.` (notice the dot)?

**Q2**: What is the terminology for this kind of type definition?

---

If I do

```
let f:'a. 'a list -> int = fun l -> List.length l;;
```

utop shows

```
val f : 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

**Q3**: Why doesn't utop shows the type `'a. 'a list -> int`?

**Q4**: When should I use this kind of type definition?

---

In addition, I can use this kind of definition in record:

```
type t = { f: 'a. 'a list -> int};; (* this is correct *)
```

but I can't use it in variants:

```
type t = Node of ('a. 'a list -> int);; (* this is wrong *)
```

**Q5**: why?

---

### Update / Summary

I did some experiments on this `forall type definition` as I can't find any articles on the web about this topic in OCaml and I want to induct to find out what's behind.

I summarise these experiments here and hope someone might give more insight.

---

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23324053/759076) below and its comments, I feel `'a.` is a kind of `force forall` thing.

**1. `'a.` in function definition**

```
let f:('a -> int) = fun x -> x + 1 (* correct *)
```

Above is fine because OCaml is free to narrow down the type of f's parameter and replace `'a` with `int`.

However,

```
let f:'a. ('a -> int) = fun x -> x + 1 (* wrong *)
```

This won't pass compiler, because it forces `f` to be applicable on `all types` via **'a.**. Apparently, it is impossible from the definition part as the only possible type for `x` is `int`.

This example is interesting as it shows the logic and magic behind OCaml's static type inferring system. The types normally show themselves naturally from the function definition, i.e., you care more about what the function does, instead of giving a type first.

To me, it makes rare sense to really use `'a.` when defining functions, as if the function's definition can handle all types, its type will naturally be `'a.`; if the function anyway cannot handle all types, it makes no sense to force all types. I guess this is one of the reasons why *the OCaml top-level usually doesn't bother showing it*

**2, `'a.` in type inferring**

```
let foo f = f [1;2;3] + f [4;5;6] (* correct *)
```

function `f` will be inferred as `int list -> int` because OCaml sees `[1;2;3]` first and it is a `int list`, so OCaml assumes `f` will take `int list`.

Also this is why the below code fails as the 2nd list is `string list`

```
let foo f = f [1;2;3] + f ["1";"2";"3"] (* wrong*)
```

Even if I know `List.length` would be a good candidate for `f`, OCaml won't allow due to the type infer system.

I thought if I force f to be `'a.`, then `f` can handle both `int list` and `string list` in `foo`, so I did:

```
let foo (f:'a. 'a list -> int) = f [1;2;3] + f ["1";"2";"3"];; (* wrong *)
```

It failed and OCaml seems not allow it. and I guess this is why *you cannot always do type inference in the presence of impredicative polymorphism, so OCaml restricts its use to record fields and object methods.*

**3. `'a.` in record**

Normally I take `'a` from the type parameter like this:

```
type 'a a_record = {f: 'a list -> int};; (* correct *)
```

However, the limitation is once you apply you get the concrete type:

```
let foo t = t.f [1;2;3] + t.f [4;5;6];;  (* correct *)
```

OCaml will infer `t` as an `int a_record`, not a `'a a_record` anymore. So the below will fail:

```
let foo t = t.f [1;2;3] + t.f ["1";"2";"3"];; (* wrong*)
```

In this case, we can use `'a.` as OCaml allows it in record type.

```
type b_record = {f: 'a. 'a list -> int};; (* correct *)
let foo t = t.f [1;2;3] + t.f ["1";"2";"3"];; (* correct *)
```

`b_record` is itself a concrete record type and its `f` can be applied on all types of lists. then our `foo` above will pass OCaml.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`'a.` means "for all types 'a". The OCaml top-level usually doesn't bother showing it, which is why it doesn't appear in the output. Any expression printed that contains type variables has an implicit forall at the start unless shown elsewhere.

When defining a function, it can be useful to add this at the start to ensure the type is polymorphic. e.g.

```
# let f : ('a -> 'a) = fun x -> x + 1;;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
```

Here, the `'a -> 'a` just constrains the function's output type to be the same as its input type, but OCaml is free to limit it further. With the `'a.`, this doesn't happen:

```
# let f : 'a. ('a -> 'a) = fun x -> x + 1;;
Error: This definition has type int -> int which is less general than
     'a. 'a -> 'a
```

You need to specify the `'a.` when defining record or object types and you want to scope the type variable to an individual member rather than to the whole object.

Comment: could you please answer **Q5**?

Comment: why I can't do `type t = Node of ('a. 'a list -> int);;`?

Comment: @JacksonTale That is an example of what is called impredicative polymorphism. You cannot always do type inference in the presence of impredicative polymorphism, so OCaml restricts its use to record fields and object methods. The changes to the type-checker made in 4.00 to allow GADTs mean it would probably not be too hard to support impredicative polymorphism more widely, but no one has implemented it yet.

Comment: @LeoWhite so `'a.` forces **for all**? that's why `let f : 'a. ('a -> 'a) = fun x -> x + 1;;` fail? as it forces `f` to be applicable for all kind of type, but apparently later it only can be applied to `int`? Is this the meaning of `'a.`?

Comment: @JacksonTale yes, and that's exactly what the answer says <`'a.` means "for all types 'a">.

Comment: Re Q5: As mentioned by Leo White you can actually put an implicit forall 'a in a union case if you declare the type using GADT syntax and use a type variable that is not a parameter of the type you're declaring: `type t = Node : ('a list -> int) -> t`